# connecting to OS X remote management VNC from Linux or Windows

Tags: mac-osx, remote-access, vnc

OSX box has remote management enabled (AppleVNCServer) and port 5900 open. Using tightvnc/ultravnc/realvnc can't connect because of "security protocol mismatch" (don't have the exact phrase). Googling yields only to posts that say "use OSXVnc" or other remote desktop solutions.

How do I connect to apple's default remote management using Linux / Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

be sure to activate the VNC password:  go to `System Preferences` / `Sharing` / `Remote Management`, press the `Computer Settings...` button, check the `VNC Viewers may control....`, and add a password there.

Comment: That's the catch - i wanted to use the non password, default authentication which as I learned by observing traffic it does kerberos authentication which none of popular VNC clients support.

Comment: I will mark this answer as accepted because that is the only reasonable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm successfully using Vinagre (version 3.10.2 on Linux) to connect to OS X Yosemite; I didn't need to enable the "VNC Viewers may control..." option in OS X.

Comment: OS X Yosemite was release in October, 4 years after the original question was asked... It does not come as a surprise that on both ends progress has been made.

Comment: It's still good to know that progress has been made. Q&A sites are Internet's collective memory

Comment: I posted this answer because this question was at the top of the Google results when I looked for this information.  I'm well aware that the software I'm using didn't exist 4 years ago; I think it's still useful for the benefit of future people who find this via Google.

Comment: The answer about Vinagre is correct on older versions, as well, at least as far back as 10.6.8 and Vinagre 3.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with a range of VNC clients I've tried - including VNC on my iPad and iPhone - I'd recommend you keep trying different clients or check your client and server configurations.